# Installing CUDA 7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install the CUDA toolkit 7.0 (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) on Ubuntu 14.04 without luck. I have been following a guide ( http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda7.0-ubuntu) stating that the when the .deb file is downloaded three simple commands should do the trick:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

However when I am executing the last command I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cuda
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add the file to your software list.

After running

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

open *Softwares & Updates* (search for it in the Dash)

In the *Other Software* tab, enable the checkbox corresponding to your package. It will be of the form

```
file:///var/cuda...
```

Then run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

If it complains about any dependencies, add those also to the above command.

For example, I got cuda-7-5 and cuda-runtime-7-5 as unmet dependencies. So my final install command was

```
sudo apt-get install cuda cuda-7-5 cuda-runtime-7-5
```

Comment: After dpkg -i cuda..... , I'm not able to find the corresponding checkbox in the Software & Updates. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I just got the same error trying to install CUDA 8 on Ubuntu 16.04. In my case, I'm doing it through the command line. I have copied the .deb file to /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2 directory, but still getting the same error... Any ideas?