# Installing cuda 6.5: likely some package issues

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, software-installation, cuda

So I had successfully install Cuda 7.5. Turns out I needed something pre 6.5, and I was having difficulty installing it.

Seemed like no matter what i did it stayed there, so I did a good search for cuda7.5 using "find" --- and found something like "cuda-repo"  in /etc/apt/sources.list.d and erased them (without making backups)

Since then, I've tried installing everything again, but to no avail.

Thinking it was a broken package, I've tried everything from

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq cuda-repo-ubuntu1404
```

to plenty of other posts like

```
    http://askubuntu.com/questions/650692/installing-cuda-7-0-on-ubuntu-14-04
```

and

```
    http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124
```

To no avail.

After doing

```
    sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
```

and

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

I get

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     cuda : Depends: cuda-7-5 (= 7.5-18) but it is not going to be installed
     libcogl15 : Depends: libegl1-mesa-drivers
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

going down the chain of dependencies manually gets me nowhere-- I went all the way down the chain and simply got to the point where it gave the same error, asking for decencies i had already added to the list! (circular dependency, if you will)

It's also very strange that 6.5 would appear to depend on 7.5

Help? I want to install cuda 6.5!